# Background Opacity Extend

Tags: html, css, joomla

Hello I have finally got the Opacity working on my website but I would like it to extend horizontally across the full width of the page. I provided an image of how I want it to look.

[image: Website Image]

The css code for the opacity is,

```
.sliderr {
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2); // transparent white
background: #fff; // Left as a fallback for older browsers
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

My website can be viewed at,

http://www.webbmaster.com.au/web-programs/questdesign/

Anyone help would be much appreciated. Have tried and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/n0wL1p3c/

```
.slider {width: 100%; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);}    
.container {width: 600px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this is what happened. http://www.webbmaster.com.au/web-programs/questdesign/ Any idea why?

Comment: this is because your .sliderr is inside your .container which has only 960px width.

Comment: Hi kgam can you take a look at my website for me if possible? I can't seem to get this to work without it effecting the main .container